# How to check is exists a tag in Jsoup html parser in android

Tags: android, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I parse tag "a" in [my html](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shtankoksu/08a48d1954bba6f961bc/raw/c0d4d18eb5f21ae7bcf36a3572a6bf4a1f9a6bf5/html) using Jsoup.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(my html);
                    Element p = doc.body().child(0);
                    Element a = p.child(0);
                    String text = a.text();
                    Log.d("tag", text);
```

But when tag "a" doesn't exist, I get exception: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

How to check is exists tag "a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `size()` method in this case. Check the element of size before it goes to main operation.

Eg:

```
if(doc.select("a").size() > 0)
{
  // then do this
}
```

This avoids `IndexOutOfBoundsException` problem.